# How to run .py files on Windows/Anaconda terminal?

Tags: python

So I installed Anaconda on my computer, and use Jupiter notebook to write a script.

I have some .py files I want to run from Windows or Anaconda Terminal, just out of curiosity.

Here are the error message I got -

C:\Users\xxx\Documents>python ex1.py
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Is there a way that I can run python on Windows without messing up the path?

Comment: I guess you need to add anaconda path to Windows environment variables.

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/a/143121/664776) is a good instruction on how to add Python to Windows PATH so you can run a Python program in Command Prompt by just typing `python ex1.py`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using *Command prompt* to parse python files.

- Open **Anaconda Prompt**,
- navigate to the folder containing your python files `cd c:\path\to\python\folder`
- execute using `python ex1.py`  where *ex1.py* is your filename

in the anaconda terminal